# Can't determine pipeline which triggered a build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm using Azure DevOps's multiple repository functionality, documented here:

[​https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops)

I have my YAML file in one repo, and the pipeline points to that YAML. The YAML has a trigger set up for another repository resource, so that when that repo gets updated, the pipeline will be triggered:

```
 resources:
   repositories:
   - repository: MyRepo
     endpoint: 'MyRepos'
     type: git
     name: RepoName
     trigger:
     - '*'
```

The documentation claims that the 'Build.SourceBranch' variable will allow me to determine which branch in MyRepo triggered the pipeline build: "When an update to one of the repositories triggers a pipeline, then the following variables are set based on triggering repository"

However, this doesn't seem to be the case. No matter what branch triggers the build, 'Build.SourceBranch' is always 'refs/heads/master', presumably because the repo that holds the YAML has 'master' as its default branch.

I can't find any environment variable that gets set to the name of the branch that triggered the build, either. So how can I get the name of the branch that triggered the build? If there's no possible way, I think this needs to be added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is:

According to the document, **`Build.SourceBranch` is set based on triggering repository. However, its value is determined by repo in which the YAML file resides in practice.**

I have done following tests. There are two repos, 'RepoA' and 'RepoB'. Both repos have two branches, 'master' and 'bran'.  And the YAML file is in 'master' of 'RepoA'

1. Commit a change in 'bran' of 'RepoB'. The value of `Build.SourceBranch` is `refs/heads/master`. It is not consistent with the documentation.
2. Commit a change in 'bran' of 'RepoA'. The value of `Build.SourceBranch` is `refs/heads/bran`. It is consistent with the documentation.
3. Commit a change in 'master' of 'RepoB'. The value of `Build.SourceBranch` is `refs/heads/master`. It is consistent with the documentation.
4. Commit a change in 'master' of 'RepoA'. The value of `Build.SourceBranch` is `refs/heads/master`. It is consistent with the documentation.

Thus, if the build is triggered by 'RepoA', `Build.SourceBranch` can successfully represent the true branch. However, if the build is triggered by 'RepoB', the value of `Build.SourceBranch` are always `refs/heads/master`.

**We have reported this issue to the product group.**

Comment: Is there a follow up? I seem to have a related problem for `Build.Repository.Name`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77825230/predefined-azure-build-pipeline-variable-build-repository-name-does-not-contain