# Azure DevOps YAML CI/CD pipelines : Build.SourceBranch is always Master on CD pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have two projects:

1. Project A containing YAML files
2. Project B containing code which is being built and deployed

I've created both CI and CD pipelines with YAML.
Problem is that when CD pipeline is triggered after CI pipeline is finished, Build.SourceBranch predefined variable is always Master (that branch on project A is used as source for Pipelines), although code pushed to Project B was on Development Branch. It seems like CD pipeline is not able to retrieve Build.SourceBranch which is a part of repo that is not "self". I need this variable in order to know which pipeline stage should be skipped/started.

I've tried multiple approaches with defining triggers but without success. This was the final solution I've tried:

**CI (yaml-defined-pipeline-from-project-a):**

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: b-dev
    name: B
    type: git
    ref: refs/heads/development
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - refs/heads/development
  - repository: b-master
    name: B
    type: git
    ref: refs/heads/master
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - refs/heads/master
...
```

**CD:**

```
trigger: none
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: b-dev
    name: B
    type: git
    ref: refs/heads/development
    trigger: none
  - repository: b-master
    name: B
    type: git
    ref: refs/heads/master
    trigger: none
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: pipeline
    source: yaml-defined-pipeline-from-project-a
    trigger: true
...
```

Is there a way for getting source branch from repo which triggered CI pipeline or I must define YAML files in Project B as well?

[CI Pipeline description on Pipelines page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEokL.png)

[CI Pipeline description after clicking on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SExAj.png)

Similar issue: [Can't determine pipeline which triggered a build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63551972/cant-determine-pipeline-which-triggered-a-build?rq=1)

Comment: if CI is triggering CD, the try Release.Artifacts.{Primary artifact alias}.SourceBranch

Comment: @Nayan That seems to work only in Classic Releases. I have CD defined as YAML pipeline.

Comment: then you can try to publish artifact in a file like json and yaml etc with you requrired content, which can be consumed by release pipeline.