# Predefined Azure build pipeline variable Build.Repository.Name does not contain expected repository name

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Let's say I have two repositories

- pipeline-repo: Contains the general pipeline like below, which will be triggered by other repositories
- trigger-repo-test: Used for testing the pipeline while triggering it upon code changes

The pipeline looks as follows:

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: trigger-repo-test
      name: MY_PROJECT/trigger-repo
      type: git
      trigger:
        - bugfix/*
        - feature/*
        - refs/heads/main
...
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: Echo repo name
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo "Build.Repository.Name: $(Build.Repository.Name)"
    - checkout: git://MY_PROJECT/$(Build.Repository.Name)
      clean: true
      displayName: Checkout $(Build.Repository.Name)
```

Note that I use the predefined variable `Build.Repository.Name` in order to checkout the triggering repo. Problem is: It does contain `pipeline-repo` when it executes the checkout task, altough the trigger is the `trigger-repo-test` repository. Why is that so?

The Bash-task interestingly echoes the correct (expected) repo: `Build.Repository.Name: trigger-repo-test`

It is hard to build a dynamic checkout, if this value is not correct ... any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

For the `Bash@3` task, the output `Build.Repository.Name: trigger-repo-test` is easily understood, as [repositories trigger update the variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#triggers).

[image]

For the last `checkout` task, it will still check the `pipeline-repo` as it's evaluated at the `compile` time `before` repositories trigger updates the variable(runtime).

You can validate this by setting reponame variable with logging command in above task, and use it in the checkout task, it will report error below, you can see it's not parsed actually.

[image]

For the `checkout` task, you need to specify hardcode or predefined value so that it can get the value at compile time.

```
- checkout: git://MY_PROJECT/test2
```

or

```
variables:
   reponame: test2
....
- checkout: git://MY_PROJECT/$(reponame)
```

Edit: if you have many repository resource in the yaml, and would like to dynamically checkout the triggering repo, you can use condition before checkout.

```
  - checkout: trigger-repo-test
    condition: eq(variables['BUILD.REPOSITORY.NAME'], 'test1')
  - checkout: trigger-repo-test2
    condition: eq(variables['BUILD.REPOSITORY.NAME'], 'test2')
```

Note if you use same repo name between different repo resource, you need to add other expression in condition.

If you don't want to use condition and checkout task, you can use bash task which contains git command, it works but more complex.

I used devops git as repository resources. If you use other git(github...etc), please change accordingly.

```
  - bash: |
      # the triggering repo uri
      uri=$(Build.Repository.Uri)
      new_uri="${uri/@/:$(PAT)@}"
      echo $new_uri
      
      # clone the repo
      git clone $new_uri
      
      # the branch
      branch=$(echo $(Build.SourceBranch) | sed 's|refs/heads/||')

      # checkout triggering branch
      cd $(Build.Repository.Name)
      git checkout $branch
```

[image]

Comment: Yes - I don't want to hard-code, this makes it really inflexible. There will be many repos triggering the pipeline. Aren't there any other options?
(But then again, the triggers need to be hard-coded as well ...)

Comment: Since the checkout task is evaluated at compile time, if you have many repos resource in the pipeline, you can use `if expression` or `condition` to check which repo should be checkout. I will update the details in the reply.

Comment: `if expression` like template condition does not work as well, since evaluated at compile time. `condition` I am aware of - yes that works, only not so nice thing is the fact that the pipeline will then have many "grey" (disabled) checkout tasks in the UI ...

But anyhow, with conditions, there seems to be no way around the fact that I have to list all repos somewhere, and a pure dynamic solution seems not possible.

Comment: With `condition` for `checkout: trigger-repo-test` is the `simplest` way and recommended, as it doesn't request credentials, and checkout the triggering repo with correct branch. If you still would like to checkout the triggering repo without condition, i also added a sample in the reply, please kindly check.

Comment: Cool, thx - I will try the bash version. I was also thinking this might be currently the only way to keep it more dynamic.

Comment: Hi @sl3dg3, may i know if there's any update? Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: I decided to go for single pipeline files in the dedicated repos, containing their triggers, and calling a central pipeline template. IMHO it is cleaner and easier to version everything by the end of the date, despite some more boiler plate yaml code ... but it is anyhow good to have the above script in the toolset!

Comment: Glad to know this! Thanks for your sharing! :)